# How to calculate the date difference in years and months in SQL Server?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2017

I am trying to calculate frequency estimate in SQL Server and I am using the following queries to get the results,

```
FORMAT(DATEADD(month,-66, DATEADD(dd, 0,DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, getdate()), 0))), 'd','us') --For -5.5 years Frequency

FORMAT(DATEADD(month,-6, DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, DATA_ASOF_TSTMP), 0))), 'd','us') --For -6 Months Frequency
```

I got the following results

```
5.5_Years_Frequency    6_Months_Frequency
          4/1/2015             3/30/2020
```

For -6 months frequency I got the end date as 3/30/2020, but March has 31 days, so, I want the result as 3/31/2020 instead of 3/30/2020 as shown below.

**Expected Results,**

```
5.5_Years_Frequency    6_Months_Frequency
          4/1/2015              3/31/2020
```

Can any one please help me to get the **expected results**?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you describe the attempted calculation in words please? Does "6 month frequency" equal "get the end date of the quarter that comes 3 quarters before the current quarter" ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But when I calculated -6 months from current quarter I am getting the end date as 3/30/2020 but March has 31 days and I should get 3/31/2020 instead of 3/30/2020.

Comment: Added answer for 6 month frequency, but your current and expected result for "5.5 year frequency" is the same in your question? And April, 1st is quarter _start date_ so it does not match the definition of 6 month frequency (which gives an _end date_).

Comment: Yes, but for 5.5 years frequency, I don't want the Quarter end date, it should be start day of next quarter, and that is how the business requested us to create the logic.

Comment: Ok, then you can just drop the `dateadd(dd, 0,` from the calculation ;-)

Comment: Got it, thank you Sander.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the calculation order:

1. Determine the quarter
2. Subtract 6 months
3. Subtract 1 day

For 6 months frequency:

```
select FORMAT(DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(month,-6, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, getdate()), 0))), 'd','us');
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6e76f10d7e7658fa05a8ccfc8cb2b92d)